# Is WPA(2)/AES or some derivative really perfectly secure?

Tags: wifi, wpa2

It is said they are uncrackable for now, but my question is how much uncrackable are they?

Of course, it requires a situation to answer this, so here comes an assumed situation(the worst possible situation for a wifi/anything in security):-

There is a device that is very portable wifi hotspot preloaded with all protocols, encryptions and profiles. Now it is using an "uncrackable" encryption in a public wifi zone, the infamous DEFCON at Las Vegas(or you can take it as BlackHat if you dislike DEFCON), with our wifi spot named something like "Hack if you can" or "The unbreakable network", keeping it on throughout the days of conference. Now, taking out the possibility of anyone gaining hardware access to it, would it be hacked? (It is publicly visible)

If yes, in how much time at the average? If no, why do you think that?

Comment: AES is secure. WPA2 probably is secure in most situations and will be superseeded by WPA3, further enhancing security. WPA shouldn't be used any longer because it uses RC4 instead of AES, which is known to be vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: in your scenario, may you provide, if 802.11X is used or if PSK is used and if PSK what properties does the password have.

Comment: It might be secure, but how much? Is it more secure than any of the hacking techniques known to human mind, is it more secure than any hacking techniques that will ever be developed, or is it more secure than any hacking techniques a few decades earlier. Is the answer an assumption or seriously meant? Can it simply not be hacked, or is another layer for our sense of security. Just for this, I gave the situation of DEFCON, where many people always get hacked, and where are hackers who will love this challenge.

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot that. It is 63-character AES256(or if something is more secure) password composed of numbers, alphabets and symbols from multiple languages that may or may not be in charmap, with or without username.

Comment: What does it mean to be hacked?  Is going after flaws in the router implementation fair game?  Is impersonating the router fair game?  Does the shared secret contain enough entropy to prevent offline attacks?  The implementation matters as much, if not more than the algorithm.  Most of the way the NSA gets access to peoples data is through cheating, not crypto breaks.

Comment: Well, no one except me knows the password. It is on for 4 days and password does not change. It can be attacked offline. And of course, I'm not gonna share the password. It's an open challenge to be hacked. By hacked, I mean a password being figured out that gives access to it. Getting hardware access to it is not possible. Of a 15000-people conference, would there be anyone who can do it in given time?

Comment: And yes, if anyone read this comment, the start and end of this question are like opposite questions, so a yes or no won't really work unless you explain it. It can mean "Yes, it is secure" or "Yes, it can be hacked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can attack this.**
 But if there're no significant improvements in cryptanalysis (quite unlikely for AES) you'll be dead a long time before the computations finish.

Now to decompose your question:

Is AES(-128/-256) by itself secure?
Yes, the best cryptologists in the world believe that AES has no significant weaknesses and recent NSA leaks shows that the NSA can't break AES either. A simple brute-force attack on AES-128 would be feasible in around 2050 for nations and in about 2070 for companies, like DES was in 1982. AES-256 isn't brute-force-able for the next two centuries.

As you've decided to go with TKIP(known to be weak)/CCMP (the authentication protocol behind WPA/WPA2), brute-forcing the password will also work.
However, even a random 8-char password is considered unbreakable, for practical attacks.
Suppose you really go for a 63-char password with characters, numbers and even un-mapped characters. Assuming you'd "only" use a 64-character (dot, comma, chars, nunbers) set, this would yield 64^63 possible passwords which is even higher than 2^256, hence brute-forcing the 256-bit AES key would be the better option!

The only attack route I can think of is that you also offer WPA.
WPA2 works like WPA with the only difference (AFAIK) that WPA2 uses AES instead of RC4 and only supports TKIP and not CCMP. I already explained that AES is safe, but RC4 is more likely to be breakable. Indeed [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/254.pdf) shows an attack against WPA's RC4. The workload still is at 2^96, meaning it's better than against WPA2 but still considered infeasible without supercomputers and a lot of time (years maybe).
Note further that if you really use TKIP, which is known to be weak, [this attack](http://jwis2009.nsysu.edu.tw/location/paper/A%20Practical%20Message%20Falsification%20Attack%20on%20WPA.pdf) seems to apply.

There's [a research paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/295.pdf) on the underlying protocols of WPA2, which is worth reading for deeper understanding. It also proves that CCMP with WPA2's handshake is safe as long as the primitives are.

EDIT: You added that AES-256 is being used. Note that this statement automatically excludes usage of WPA. Hence the above attack on WPA doesn't apply. But the second still does if WPA2 is used with TKIP.

Comment: Edits to make the post readable - please don't use bold like that. It actually makes it much harder to read.

Comment: So, would that mean it won't be hacked under the given situation. I actually thought that though whitehats haven't found a vulnerability in it so far, what is the chance that some blackhat knows it? There can be key collisions in bruteforcing, and it never takes the full time expected. If it is secure enough to not be hacked even when we challenge an over 15000-member hacker conference and keep challenge up for 4 days(without changing password), then it is really the most secure we can use. It can be hacked, but there are some limitations to analyze.eg.There are not years available to hack it.

Comment: Well, if you don't consider implementation flaws and weak passwords (the largest threats!). Than it actually is impossible to break the configuration you described, as the protocol has been proven secure, AES is secure and the password is secure..

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is "no".  We know from long experience that nothing is "perfectly" secure.

AES has no significant flaws that we know about today, and has key sizes that are large enough to resist brute force attacks forever.  People have been studying it for a decade, looking for weaknesses, and have only come up with some weak keys, and reduced round attacks.  While we consider the chances unlikely, there is no guarantee that a fatal weakness doesn't exist.

Given the history of breaks so far, I don't think AES will prove to be the weak point of WPA2.

WPA2 is less mature than AES, and while the theories are good, and again nobody's published an exploit yet, we know that most security failures end up being flaws in protocol designs or implementations.

It's ironic that you use the phrase "or derivative" in your question.  Many protocol security flaws are created by implementations that offer backward compatibility.  "Set this flag to upgrade from Version 2 to Version 3" turns out to be exploitable by an attacker far more often than you might think.  WPA2 by itself may be fine, a mythical WPA3 might be fine, but an access point that offers both might hide a fatal flaw.